# Alternative to function findInterval

Tags: r

I'm using function findInterval to locate the position of another variables in the same row.

Example:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(x=seq(1,10,1),y=rnorm(10,1))
val <- 0.5

df$x[findInterval(val,df$y, all.inside=TRUE)]
```

This give error, the vector **must be sorted non-decreasingly**

Is there an alternative? I have quite few columns and flipping columns back-and-forth is not that handy.

With re-ordering of course all works:

```
ordered.df <-df[order(df[ ,"y"], decreasing=FALSE), ]

ordered.df$x[findInterval(val,ordered.df$y, all.inside=TRUE)]
```

Comment: no this doesn't work, just test it yourself...it should return index of column `x` where the `val = 0.5` falls closest to the `interval` of values in `y`. This doesn't seems to do it.

Comment: May be I messed it up. Sorry, I was testing on another `seed`.

Comment: So, you want to do a rolling join (next observation carried backwards) without sorting? I don't believe that could be made efficient.

Comment: Is `approx(x=df$y,y=df$x,xout=val,method="constant")$y` what you are looking for? I confess I don't think to fully understand your question.

Comment: I just want to find location (row) where value `val`=0.5 matches closest to value in column `y`. So it should give index of a row where the match is closest given `val` and `y` values.

Comment: @Nicola: This is great! Works! I looked into that `approx` function, but I cannot find anything like findInterval function has, and that's `all.inside=TRUE`, this gives the last value if out of range. With your solution in this case gives NA. If you would submit as answer I would accept already. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for `approx`, with the `constant` method:

```
approx(x=df$y,y=df$x,xout=val,method="constant",yright=nrow(df)-1,yleft=1)$y
```

For the behaviour outside the interval, check the `yleft` and `yright` args.

Answer (score 3):

I think you actually want a rolling join. That can't be done efficiently without sorting.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(x=seq(1,10,1),y=rnorm(10,1))
val <- 0.5

library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df)
setkey(DT, y)
#     x          y
# 1:  8 -0.2650612
# 2:  9  0.3131471
# 3:  1  0.4395244
# 4: 10  0.5543380
# 5:  2  0.7698225
# 6:  4  1.0705084
# 7:  5  1.1292877
# 8:  7  1.4609162
# 9:  3  2.5587083
#10:  6  2.7150650

DT[.(val), roll = "nearest"]
#    x   y
#1: 10 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try which.min

```
df$x[which.min(abs(val - dt$y)]
```

Comment: quality is low, please explain a little better.